# What is the difference between onCompletion and try/finally for Flows?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The documentation on Flow describes why `emit` should never be run in a try/catch block:

> Flow implementations never catch or handle exceptions that occur in downstream flows. From the implementation standpoint it means that calls to `emit` and `emitAll` shall never be wrapped into `try { ... } catch { ... }` blocks. Exception handling in flows shall be performed with `catch` operator and it is designed to only catch exceptions coming from upstream flows while passing all downstream exceptions...
> **The same reasoning can be applied to the `onCompletion` operator that is a declarative replacement for the finally block.**

However, the documentation for `onCompletion` specifies

> Unlike `catch`, this operator reports exception that occur both upstream and downstream and observe exceptions that are thrown to cancel the flow. Exception is empty if and only if the flow had fully completed successfully.

So: what is the difference between using `finally` and `onCompletion`, if it's not transparency to downstream exceptions?  There are many use cases where `onCompletion` would be extremely difficult to use, notably any "try-with-resources"-based flow where there is state not passed along in the flow.

Specifically, I would be satisfied with a piece of code demonstrating a behavior difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion after using both is that:

- `onCompletion` is useful when the cleanup code needs to know whether the flow succeeded or failed
- `try`/`finally` is useful when you always want to run the exact same cleanup regardless of whether the flow succeeded or failed

This is because `onCompletion` receives the failure reason as a parameter, or
`null` if the flow finished normally without an exception.

```kotlin
myFlow.onCompletion { failure ->
    if (failure == null) println("Success") else println("Failure")
}
```

From the docs:

> The key advantage of onCompletion is a nullable `Throwable` parameter of the lambda that can be used to determine whether the flow collection was completed normally or exceptionally.
>
> https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#declarative-handling

To achieve the same thing with `try`/`catch` is a bit more verbose (and actually needs a `catch` instead of a `finally`:

```kotlin
try {
    collect()
} catch (t: Throwable) {
    println("Failure")
    throw t
}
println("Success")
```

You mentioned try-with-resources. I think it's important to note the difference between `try`/`finally` in a flow builder and `try`/`finally` in a flow collector. The former is useful for closing resources used by the flow; the latter is more analogous to `onCompletion`.

The example above shows a `try`/`catch` in a flow collector. It could be easily replaced with `try`/`finally` if you don't need to know whether it succeeded or failed. On the other hand, using `finally` for cleanup in a flow builder would look like this:

```kotlin
flow {
    val myResource = openResource()
    try {
        myResource.values.forEach { emit(it) }
    } finally {
        myResource.cleanup()
    }
}
```

In reality you'd probably do this with `use` rather than `try`/`finally`. As you noted, it isn't something you could do with `onCompletion` (or a `try`/`catch`/`finally` in the flow collector), because it relies on state that lives inside the flow builder. I think it's one of the great benefits of flows that each stage of the flow can encapsulate its setup and cleanup in this way.

In actual fact, `onCompletion` sort of combines the flow collector and flow builder examples above. That's because in the case where the flow terminated without an exception, `onCompletion` can emit new values. The fact that it can't emit values when the flow failed with an exception is an artificial restriction that, when you look at the source code, actually complicates the implementation.

By writing our own flow operator we can overcome that constraint:

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.finally(block: suspend FlowCollector<T> -> Unit) {
    try {
        emitAll(this@finally)
    } finally {
        block(t)
    }
}
```

With the above operator, `someFlow.finally { emit(...) }` will always emit a new value, even if the flow failed with an exception. I'm not sure whether it violates the prohibition on wrapping `emit` with `try`/`catch`, but it doesn't feel like a particularly good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, both `onCompletion` and `finally` will be run in case of upstream exception, downstream exception, and normal completion. In that sense, they have no difference in behaviour (to my knowledge), so I can't craft an example to exhibit a difference.

One addition though is that `onCompletion`'s lambda gives access to a `FlowCollector` which can `emit()` further elements to the downstream flow (when no exception occurred).

I guess apart from that, the only difference here is style. Just like `.filter{}` would be the same as `if(condition) emit(it)`.